# Keyboard Listener when Applet Not Focused

Tags: java, applet, awt, keyboard-events

I am creating an applet to listen for hotkeys to be pressed, such as F12 or F11 to stop/start the process of the program.

How do I listen for these hotkeys even when the program isn't the one active on the screen?

Comment: Don't use a gawd-awful tool for this need, Java, but instead use any better tool you can, such as AutoIt if for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I listen for these hotkeys even when the program isn't the one active on the screen?

You can't.  Nor should you.  <kbd>F11</kbd> is used in FF (for example) to go to full-screen.

Comment: F11 was just an example

Comment: Well it was a very poor example.  Not that it makes much difference, since FF/F-11 was just an example..

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using the absolutely worst tool for your need that can be imagined, Java, since it tries to remain as far from the OS as possible. Instead why not use a better tool, such as AutoIt V3 if for Windows.